# método para decodificar con jwt-simple no funciona nodejs

Tags: nodejs, express, jwt

Verán, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
exports.crearToken = function(req,res){

var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
        var moment = require('moment');
        var payload = {
                sub:req.datos,
                iat:moment().unix(),
                exp:moment().add(1,'days').unix()
            };
            var x = jwt.encode(payload,'misecretoken');
            res.status(200).send(x);


        }
```

se crea el token y luego utilizo esta función para decodificar

```
exports.prueba = function(req,res){ 
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
    var moment = require ('moment');
    var token = req.token;
    var z = jwt.decode(token,'misecretoken');

res.status(200).send(z);
```

}

el problema es que no lo decodifica, me devuelve encriptado el token :(

ahora, si utilizo el método de decodificación al crear el token si funciona, ¿puede alguien explicarme por que pasa esto?

```
 exports.crearToken = function(req,res){

   var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
        var moment = require('moment');
        var payload = {
                sub:req.datos,
                iat:moment().unix(),
                exp:moment().add(1,'days').unix()
            };
            var x = jwt.encode(payload,'misecretoken');
            var z = jwt.decode(x,'misecretoken');
            res.status(200).send(z);
        }
```

Comment: ¿Seguro que estás recibiendo un token en la petición?

Comment: Hola, si estoy seguro ya que me devolvia el token solo que encriptado

Comment: **Nota:** me refiero a petición, es decir, petición HTTP. Te pregunté si en en la petición está el token (`req.token`). El paquete `jwt` no guarda ningún estado, puedes importarlo desde varios lugares y, si recibe un token válido, lo decodificará correctamente.

Comment: A eso me refiero, el req.token no viene vació, viene con el token pero le paso el decode y me lo devuelve encriptado todavia

Answer (score 0):

Estas tratando de aplicar un `decode` a `payload` la cual aun no esta decodificada, Por eso da error.

quedaria tal que asi:

```
var x = jwt.encode(payload,'misecretoken');
var z = jwt.decode(x,'misecretoken');
res.status(200).send(z);
```

Comment: Esa ultima parte la puse como ejemplo ya que así no lo tengo en el código, el problema es cuando las uso separadas, en la función prueba cuando aplico el decode no funciona

Comment: Si lo tienes en el mismo archivos pon la variable `jwt` en global.